# cache_unless still computes the cache key although the condition is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, russian-doll-caching

I have a simple fragement cache :

```
-cache_unless user_signed_in?, ['show', @question, @question.user.username, @question.user.score, @question.user.avatar_url] do
```

The page is not being cached when I'm singed in, which is what I want, however, the cache key is still being computed and I can see ActiveRecord queries in my log.

I was expecting that the cache doesn't compute the new cache key if the condition was true.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use simple if else logic :

```
if user_signed_in? 
  #render uncached resources
else
  #cache 
end
```